# Does MacOS 11.5.2 log mains failures?

Tags: battery, power, login

If a MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2019) has its charger plugged in and the mains power goes off and back on, is that recorded in any log?  Maybe something monitoring that USB port?  (Nothing in console has "usb" in the title.)

And if so, does it work when the lid is closed (presumably sleeping)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If a MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2019) has its charger plugged in and the mains power goes off and back on, is that recorded in any log?

Located in `/private/var/log/powermanagement/` there are, e.g., `2021.09.17.asl` *files* that will contain entries, e.g.,:

```
15:57:00.586812-0400    powerd  Summary- [System: PrevIdle DeclUser kDisp] Using Batt(Charge: 100)
```

As well as, e.g.,:

```
15:59:18.910800-0400    powerd  Summary- [System: PrevIdle DeclUser kDisp] Using AC(Charge: 100)
```

Which in my case shows when I last switched from battery to AC power yesterday when I was testing something I needed to be on battery power for.

Note that these *logs* were viewable in **Console** when I *double-clicked* them in **Finder**.

**Notes:**

As these *files* are *binary* and one could `grep 'Using Batt'` on them, while it would return e.g. `Binary file 2021.09.17.asl matches`, nonetheless, one can use `syslog` instead of **Console**, e.g.:

```
syslog -d /private/var/log/powermanagement/ | grep 'Using Batt'
```

To get *output*, e.g.:

```
Sep 17 15:57:00 [edit]-MacBook-Pro powerd[111] <Notice>: Summary- [System: PrevIdle DeclUser kDisp] Using Batt(Charge: 100)
```

<sup>I too am using a MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2019).</sup>

Comment: I don’t recall seeing “power” in console, either.  But I’ll look again.

Comment: @WGroleau, RE: "I don’t recall seeing “power” in console, either." --  Please reread my answer as I stated "Note that these _logs_ were viewable in **Console** when I _double-clicked_ them in **Finder**."

Comment: Ah, sō desu ka …

Comment: @WGroleau, Hai,-sōdesu

Comment: Also "Using AC."  the two together tells me what I was after, which was how long the mains were out.  Only fifteen seconds.   And it DID log with the lid closed..